# (probability + algebra ) in cryptography.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we know $n$ - which is a product of two unknown primes
- and also an integer m such that $a^m \equiv$  1 mod n for all a prime to
n. We see that any such m must be even (as we see by taking a = -1).
We first check whether m/2 has the same property, in which case we can
replace m by m/2. If $a^{m/2}$ is ***not*** $\equiv$ 1 mod n for all a prime to n, then we
must have $a^{m/2}$ is ***not*** $\equiv$ 1 mod n for at least 50% of the a's in (Z/nZ)*

This is an extract in the description of RSA from the book on cryptography by Koblitz. It will be very helpful if anyone can give a proof of the last statement.

Comment: Prove that the $a$ for which the congruence holds, form a subgroup; if it's a proper subgroup, it can't be more than half of the group (this assumes you know a little group theory).

Comment: @lab: The question says "for all a prime to n." try a=20, m=3

Comment: @Myderson: ok. I got it. I used lagrange theorem for the group theory part.

Comment: @JishnuRay, sorry for the confusion. Please find Point#6 of http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/csgnotes/lambda.pdf and observe that $\lambda(n)$ is even for $n>2$

Comment: Ray, that's good --- now write it up and post it as an answer. Then, after some time passes, you can accept your answer. Oh, and careful about the spelling of my name.